# Actions of Thompson group F

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Does anybody know the actions of Thompson group F which are not conjugate to the standard one?

Motivation is to find actions such that the Schreier graph of the action does not contain a binary tree.

I've decided to ask a separate question on the motivation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130216/actions-of-thompson-group-f-ii)

Comment: Actions on what? Circle?

Comment: Misha, yes, on circle. But I am also interested in any actions of this group.

Comment: Misha, I am interested in those actions, where the Schreier graph of the action does not contain a binary tree. Does this kind of actions are known? 

Comment: The question seems to concern transitive actions on discrete sets. Actually, I don't know if $F$ admits a Schreier graph of subexponential growth (or even with no bilipschitz binary tree) besides the ones factoring through the action of an abelian quotient of $F$. 

Comment: Isn't there a bijection between transitive actions on discrete sets and conjugacy classes of subgroups, given by point stabilizers and coset action respectively? I assume there are infinitely many conjugacy classes of subgroups, which would seem to indicate that the actions are inequivalent. 

Comment: Yves, I don't this kind of actions either.

Comment: Ian, I was thinking about actions on a circle and conjugation via homeomorphisms. With the discrete sets you are right, there are plenty of non conjugate actions.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4017 might be relevant. 

Comment: For every group action on the circle you can always do a Denjoy blowup to construct a new topological group action not conjugate to the original one.   

Comment: Misha, could this potentially give an action with Schreier graph of subexponential growth? I don't know this construction, could you please cite something for me.

Comment: I think the question is quite hopeless. Nekrashevych, de la Salle and myself discovered a very large list of groups where amenability can be extracted out of recurrency of an action. But all known to me actions of F contain binary tree, which means that the simple random walk on Schreier graph is transient.

Comment: Could you clarify if you are concerned with transitive actions on discrete sets (as the fact that you consider the Schreier graph suggests)? the action on the interval is not one, and you didn't say what is the standard action (the action on the dyadics in the open interval?) 

Comment: Yves, I am concerned with transitive actions on discrete sets. I was (probably naive) thinking that the most natural actions appear from homeomorphisms of the circle and I want to check if I don't miss something. But the standard does not work, since it is not transient. Of course I want something that does not come from quotient.

Comment: Note that you haven't yet said what is the "standard" action. If you look at actions on orbits on the open interval, the stabilizers are pairwise distinct and therefore, since $Aut(F)$ is countable, you also have continuum many actions that are pairwise non-conjugate by automorphisms of $F$. It mayby happens, however, than none of these actions is fine for you.

Comment: By standard I mean homeomorphisms of the interval.

Comment: @Kate: this is vague.

Comment: Yes, Yves, I mean piecewise linear homeomorphisms of the unit interval that preserve orientation and whose non-differentiable points are dyadic rationals and whose slopes are all powers of 2. 

Comment: @Kate: OK to call this the standard action... but this is not a transitive action on a discrete set. When you say that for the standard action there is a binary tree on the schreier graph, which action do refer to?

Comment: restriction to Z[1/2]. 

Comment: Yves, PS: sorry, I am thinking that I write clearly, but in fact I don't...

Answer (score 5):

$F$ is bi-orderable, so if you care about actions by homeomorphisms on the line, you can pick up a bi-ordering and produce a dynamical realization: a faithful almost free action ( see Proposition 3.4 and Example 3.5 in this paper of Navas http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.2466  for a "non-standard" action of $F$). For the discrete case, the proof of Proposition 1.8 in the same paper might be an inspiration... All the bi-orderings of $F$ were described by Navas and Rivas here http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1688 . (As a side remark, in one dimensional dynamics one usually consider two actions equivalent if they are semi-conjugate, rather than conjugate)

(this was meant to be just a comment, but don't have enough points...:)

Answer (score 3):

Well, every action of $F$ corresponds to a subgroup $H\leq F$ in the standard way.  Specifically, the "standard" action on the interval corresponds to the stabilizers of various points in the interval.  The Schreier graphs of these actions have been studied [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4017).

If you want other actions of Thompson's group $F$, you need to look at subgroups that aren't just the stabilizer of a point.  If you want to avoid a binary tree in the Schreier graph, you want this subgroup to be "large" enough so that every conjugate intersects the $\langle x_0,x_1\rangle$ monoid.  However, if you want the action to be faithful, the subgroup cannot be so large that it contains the commutator subgroup.

Of course, it's not clear how to make this concept of "large" precise.  I suppose one possible definition is "does not stabilize any point in $(0,1)$".

With that in mind, here are some relatively "large" subgroups of Thompson's group $F$.  I have no idea whether their Schreier graphs contain binary trees.

1. Given any subset of the dyadics (or indeed any subset of the interval), one could consider the consider certain Cantor sets inside the interval, such as the set of points whose binary expansion subgroup of elements of $F$ that stabilize that subset.  One interesting subset to look at might be $\{\ldots,\frac{1}{16},\frac18,\frac14,\frac12,\frac34,\frac78,\frac{15}{16},\ldots\}$.  Another might be the set of dyadics of the form $k/4^n$, where $k$ is an odd integer.  Finally, one can consider certain Cantor sets inside of $[0,1]$, such as the set of points whose binary expansion has a "$0$" in every odd-numbered position.
2. There is a copy of $F_3$ inside of $F$, which can be described as follows:

   - Start by labeling the interval $[0,1]$ with the letter $A$.
   - Now, whenever you subdivide an $A$ interval, label the left half $A$ and the right half $B$
   - Finally, whenever you subdivide a $B$ interval, label both halves $A$.
   - Let $H$ be the subgroup of elements of $F$ that map linearly between the intervals of two dyadic subdivisions in a label-preserving way.  Then $H$ is isomorphic to $F_3$.

   This construction can be generalized to give a copy of $F_n$ for any $n$.
3. More generally, it is possible to find copies of many different diagram groups inside of $F$ by using different labelings.  The copy of $F_3$ above corresponds to the diagram group for the monoid presentation $\langle A,B \mid A=AB, B=A^2\rangle$.  See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005114) by Guba and Sapir for some further examples.
4. Another source of "large" subgroups comes from various laminations of the unit disk.  Given any lamination, one can consider the subgroup consisting of all elements of $F$ that preserve the lamination.  These groups have not been studied at all, though in a [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4225) Bradley Forrest and I have considered an analogous subgroup of Thompson's group $T$.

Comment: Thanks Jim for this list of actions. Currently I don't see if any of those does not contain binary tree and are faithful.

Comment: @Kate: a homomorphism from $F$ to any group is either injective of factors through the abelianization. In other words, any action (on any set) of $F$ not factoring through $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is faithful. Still equivalently, any nontrivial normal subgroup of $F$ contains $[F,F]$.

Comment: @Kate: Using Yves's argument, it follows that all of the actions above are faithful.  I have no idea whether the Schreier graphs contain binary trees, although if I had to guess, I would guess the Schreier graph for *every* faithful action of $F$ contains a binary tree.

Comment: Yves, yes, this is clear to me... But one needs to check this for the specified actions, which is what I just did. 

Comment: Jim, this would be interesting to know, my intuition suggests the same, but I might be wrong. 

Comment: It seems to me that any orbital Schreier graph of any dyadic point will contain the tree.