# Actions of Thompson group F. II

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a group generated by symmetric finite set $S$ and acting on $X$. *The Schreier graph* of the action is the graph with vertex set $X$ and $(x,y)$ is an edge if there is $s\in S$ such that $x=sy$.

> Does there exists a faithful
>   transitive action of the Thompson
>   group F on a discrete set $X$ such
>   that the Schreier graph of this action
>   do not contain a binary tree?

Comment: What do you mean by ``contain"? As a subgraph or  coarsely embedded?

Comment: For the applications the best would be to know that it does not coarsely contain. But firstly, I want to know about containment as a subgraph only (I suspect that there is no such action).

Comment: The subgraph interpretation is more difficult because that depends on the generating set. 

Comment: I am thinking about "avoiding" of the free semigroup and this can not be done for known to me actions. But yes, you are right for the general situation. 

Comment: Free subsemigroups don't give you trees as subgraphs, only coarsely embedded trees.  

Comment: actually I'm not sure I know any bounded degree graph with a subgraph isomorphic to a 3-regular tree but with no coarsely embedded 3-regular tree.

Comment: An exotic action of $F$ is the following: let $F_4$ be the set of elements in $F$ with all slopes integral powers of $4$ and $X=F/F_4$.

Comment: Kate, did you check it for the standard action on dyadics with the standard generators? If yes, at which points you can choose the root of the tree? 

Comment: For the standard actions with standard generators, I think there is no binary tree, but there are trees branching almost as quick.


Comment: For the standard action I've used the description of Dima Savchuk, http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0043.pdf. It contains the binary tree quasiisometrically, in fact with constant 2. This violates recurrence that we are looking for. Most likely such action does not exists, but I don't see the proof.

Comment: Yes, this is clear. I thought you want subgraph... 

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question as stated is yes, there is no binary tree as a subgraph for the standard action with standard generators (but there is a binary tree for some generating set). It follows from Proposition 1 in this paper of Savchuk http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0043.pdf and can be checked directly also.